# lilypond engraving lyrics to small part with voices

Tags: lilypond

I try to set a sheet of music using lilypond 2.18 and i have difficulties to engrave the lyrics to a small part of the score where I use `<< { } \\ { } >>` to get a second voice to the staff. The part of the lyrics which belongs under the two voice part will placed behind the part.

```
\version "2.18.2"

global = {
  \time 4/4
  \key d \major
}

melody = \relative c' {
  \global 
  e2( e8. ) fis16 fis8 fis |    
  << {fis2(    fis8.)  } \\ {fis4( d4)( fis8.) } >> fis16 fis8 fis  | 

}

words = \lyricmode {
  See. Die Lap -- pen hoch!___ die Anker fort

}

\score {
  <<
    \new Staff { \melody }
    \addlyrics { \words }
  >>
  \layout { }
}
```

[image: score]

I like to render the "*hoch!*" under the first **fis** in the second bar. Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use implicit voices but have one voice continue.

```
\version "2.18.2"

global = {
  \time 4/4
  \key d \major
}

melody = \relative c' {
  \global 
  e2( e8. ) fis16 fis8 fis |    
  << {\voiceOne fis2(    fis8.) \oneVoice }
 \new Voice { \voiceTwo fis4( d4)( fis8.) } >> fis16 fis8 fis  | 

}

words = \lyricmode {
  See. Die Lap -- pen hoch!___ die Anker fort

}

\score {
  <<
\new Staff { \melody }
\addlyrics { \words }
  >>
  \layout { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest a route of using voices ("null" voices, in this case) to control the alignment of lyrics.

Write the music however you wish: voices here, voices there, so on and so forth.

However, when it comes your lyrics, *align* them to their own *voice*:

```
\version "2.18.2"

\layout {
 \context {
  \Score
   \accepts "NullVoice"
 }
}

global = {
 \time 4/4
 \key d \major
}

melody = \relative c' {
 e2( e8.) fis16 fis8 fis  
 fis2~ fis8. fis16 fis8 fis
}

words = \lyricmode {
 See. Die Lap -- pen
 hoch! __ die An -- ker
}

music = \relative c' {
 e2( e8.) fis16 fis8 fis  
 <<{
  fis2( fis8.) fis16
  }\\{
  fis4( d4 fis8.) s16
 }>> fis8 fis
}

\score {
 <<
  \new NullVoice = "melody" \melody
  \new Staff <<
   \global
   \music
  >>
  \new Lyrics \lyricsto "melody" \words
 >>
 \layout {}
}
```

Happy Lilyponding!

Answer (score 0):

this is better code :

    \version "2.18.2"

```
global = {
  \time 4/4
  \key d \major
}

melody = \relative c' {
  \global 
  e2( e8. ) fis16 fis8 fis |    
  << {\voiceOne fis2(    fis8.) \oneVoice }
 \new Voice { \voiceTwo fis4( d4)( fis8.) } >> fis16 fis8 fis  | 

}

words = \lyricmode {
  See._ __ Die Lap -- pen hoch!_ __ die Anker fort

}

\score {
  <<
\new Staff { \melody }
\addlyrics { \words }
  >>
  \layout { }
}
```